# Alternative to using setTimeout with AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hey guys, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
setInterval('getAllWords()', 2000);

function getAllWords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "queries.php",
        data: "action=all",
        success: function(data){
            dataArray = data.split('|');
            $('#words').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                if ((dataArray[i]).length > 1) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + dataArray[i] + '</li>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**ELABORATION (?)**
*This basically connect every 2 seconds to the database and checks for updated words, is there an easy way to implement a `push` request or something to minimise the database activity?*

**MORE INFO:**
*My hosting doesn't support installing of AJAX Push servers and they won't install one for me*

## :(

Comment: check out APE http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: I can't istall servers on my hosting :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't install a push server, consider this hack:

Run an infinite loop that only sends an answer to your ajax request once there's something new (while(true) { check for updated words}).

In your ajax code you can then simply start a request and as soon as it's finished start a new one (eg. readyState == 4 --> start new request)

Comment: oooh, I like this - is there any adverse affects I should be worried about though?

Comment: your server will keep a socket open for as long as the script is running. if you get a lot of concurrent users your ports might get flooded and no new users could join - though if you're just starting this might be a minor concern.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: It does seem that way, I don't suppose you have some form of JavaScript/jQuery example?

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem. I suggest starting with the External Links section at the bottom of the Wikipedia page for practical implementation advice.

Comment: Next question is: Is there anyway of doing that without having to install a server on the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need internet explorer support, you could use [webSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)

Otherwise there are several standard ways of implementing [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Here is a way to implement [long polling using php](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) - use google to find more :)

Answer (score 0):

If query caching is enabled on your db server, then this shouldn't be a cause for worry. The query cacher will not load the db until the words field is updated.

On other note,

I prefer using setTimeout than using setInterval. What if response from server takes more than 2 secs to return?
setInterval will issue request again even if previous request is not complete.

So,
I'd use this

```
function getAllWords() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "queries.php",
        data: "action=all",
        success: function(data){
            dataArray = data.split('|');
            $('#words').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                if ((dataArray[i]).length > 1) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + dataArray[i] + '</li>');
                }
            }

            setTimeout(getAllWords,2000);
        }
    });
}

getAllWords();
```

Answer (score 0):

to minize the db activity, you could:

- use a record to save whether something changed in your keywords instead of checking directly in the keywords'table.

OR

- use Application scope variable : which do not exist natively in PHP. But if you have a APC installed on your server, you can use an APC variable.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `setInterval()` function, however efficiency of the method depend upon your requirement.

Please let me know your requirement.

Comment: Allow me to say why you were downvoted (even if I didn't vote you down) - It's because you haven't actually put an answer in the "answer box", you have just said what I said and then asked another question...

Comment: oopss, I was just assumed that you have written setTimeout(),